# Parallel async task execution in switch case

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asynchronous, .net-core, task-parallel-library

I have a switch case condition with `async` `Task` methods inside `async` `Task` method Message.

```
async static Task Message()
{
    switch (message.Text)
    {
        case "1":
            task1().Wait();
            break;
        case "2":
            task2().Wait();
            break;
        case "3":                               
            task3().Wait();
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

and `task1` for example itself. When it's completed, the cycle goes back to the `Message` method. `task2` and `task3` are similar to `task1` just with different text info.

```
async static Task task1()
{
    try
    {               
        while (true)
        {
            //some code
            Message().Wait();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error" + ex);
    }
}
```

The problem is when some user is inside `task1`(or `task2`, `task3`), other user can't get response from the `Message` method until `task1` is finished. The question is how to execute the tasks in switch case in parallel.
My main method

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        Parallel.Invoke(
        () => CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run(),
        () => Message().Wait());
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error" + ex);
    }
}
```

here is `CreateHostBuilder`

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
        {
            //
        });
```

Comment: Why use a switch/case with a wait, instead of a continuation?

Comment: @Christopher what u mean?

Comment: Was the problem resolved?

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron no, the problem is in inner Task task1(or task2,3). It accepts only one user until this task is finished. Don't know how to solve this issue. May be problem is in GetUpdatesAsync method which also exist in Message method, or using of concurrent dictionary(from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51933004/save-user-messages-sent-to-bot-and-send-finished-form-to-other-user) limits number of users. Can u help please.

Comment: You could try either of them  `AUTO RESET EVENT`,  `MUTEX`,  `SEMAPHORE` to manage parallel process. You can have a look on [official docs here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/overview-of-synchronization-primitives#waithandle-class-and-lightweight-synchronization-types)

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron ty for response. I tried a lot of different ways, but stucked with this issue. Posted a new question with detailed explanation(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68859452/how-to-get-parallel-access-to-the-method-for-multiple-users). I will be grateful, if u will help to solve this problem.

Comment: Thanks for the update , I will try to have a look on your link. Let me know if you have any further concern.

Answer (score 1):

Use the await keyword instead of `.Wait()`. `Wait()` blocks the current thread, however `await` is non-blocking and works with a continuation callback. Moreover, the compiler should issue a warning when you do not use `await` in an `async` method

```
async static Task Message()
{
    switch (message.Text)
    {
        case "1":
            await task1();
            break;
        case "2":
            await task2();
            break;
        case "3":
            await task3();
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

```
async static Task task1()
{
    try
    {
        while (true)
        {
            //some code
            await Message();

        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error" + ex);
    }

}
```

In your main method:

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
 
        Task t1 = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().RunAsync();
        Task t2 = Message();
    
        await Task.WhenAll(t1, t2);
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Exception Handling is a pet peeve of mine. Catching Exception is a terrible idea, unless it is for logging and you let it go on afterwards.  I consider code like that a deadly sin of exception handling. There are two articles on exception handling that explain why much better then I could: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/ | https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9538/Exception-Handling-Best-Practices-in-NET

Comment: edited code , but it didn't work cause of main method. I can't use await for CreateHostBuilder, that's why await can't be added to Message in main. Any suggestion? Added main method in description

Comment: Can you include your `CreateHostBuilder` method in your post? `await` can only be used for async methods.

Comment: added. CreateHostBuilder and Message must work in parallel

Comment: @coxcoxgo Please check the updated answer

Comment: @coxcoxgo Did you use `RunAsync()`?

Comment: where and how to use RunAsync()? added your code for Main, no errors. But still user2 can't get response from Message until user1 finish Task1.

Comment: @coxcoxgo I had edited the code in `Main` once more, did you add the updated code?

Comment: yes, updated it. But still user2 can't get response from Message until user1 finish Task1.

Comment: @AmalK ty for your response. Can u look please at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68859452/how-to-get-parallel-access-to-the-method-for-multiple-users It's related question in deep